# R: parse large unstructured xml file

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I have a very complicated xml file need to parse and present in dataframe format in R. The structure may similar to the following example. The nodes are not paralleled.

```
<Root>
  <A>
   <info1>a</info1>
     <child>
       <info2>b</info2>
       <info3>c</info3>
       <info4>d</info4>
     </child>
   <info5>e</info5>
  </A>
  <B>
   <info6>f</info6>
   <info7>g</info7>
  </B>
</Root>
```

I come up some code to parse the file:

```
doc <- xmlParse(file="sample.xml", useInternal = TRUE)
rootnode <- xmlRoot(doc)
df1<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(rootnode, "//Root/A"))
df2<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(rootnode, "//Root/B"))
Final<-cbind.data.frame(df1,df2, all=TRUE)
```

The result returned as:  (all the value form node were shrink together)

```
info1 child info5 info6 info7
  a    bcd    e     f     g
```

However, the ideal result I want is:

```
info1 info2 info3 info4 info5 info6 info7
  a     b     c     d     e     f     g
```

Because there are large number of nodes in the xml file similar to the situation above, it is not wise to manually manipulate the dataframe.
I also try to change the path statement to "//Root/A/child", then all the value under node A and node B will be missed. 
Does anyone could offer the solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can try `xmlToList` and `unlist` to reduce `xml` data in named vector format. The names can be changed using `gsub` to match OP's expectations as:

```
library(XML)
result <- unlist(xmlToList(xmlParse(xml)))
#Change the name to refer only child 
names(result) <- gsub(".*\\.(\\w+)$","\\1", names(result))
result 
# info1 info2 info3 info4 info5 info6 info7 
# "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"   "g"
```

**Data:**

```
xml <- "<Root>
  <A>
  <info1>a</info1>
  <child>
  <info2>b</info2>
  <info3>c</info3>
  <info4>d</info4>
  </child>
  <info5>e</info5>
  </A>
  <B>
  <info6>f</info6>
  <info7>g</info7>
  </B>
  </Root>"
```

Comment: Thank you very much MKR, based on your code, I directly data.frame to the unlist result. I get the dataframe with only the value from all the node but without the column names(node name). Do you know somehow I can add all the node name along with all the values? Much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In a less structured XML, it is better to do the following:

```
library(XML)
Final <- data.frame(xmlToList(rootnode), recursive = T, use.names = T)
```

If you don't like the automatically set column names, you can simply do `use.names = F` and set your own names.

Comment: Thank you very much Kim, I tried the code, however, it gave me the error message as: arguments imply differing number of rows:1, 0.

Answer (score 0):

Match the nodes using `starts-with()`

```
> doc = xmlParse(xml)
> xpathSApply(doc, "//*[starts-with(name(), 'info')]", xmlValue)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
> xpathSApply(doc, "//*[starts-with(name(), 'info')]", xmlName)
[1] "info1" "info2" "info3" "info4" "info5" "info6" "info7"
```

so

```
query <- "//*[starts-with(name(), 'info')]"
setNames(
    xpathSApply(doc, query, xmlValue),
    xpathSApply(doc, query, xmlName)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, the xml file is just a sample, my actual xml file is way more complicate than this and each node name is totally different from others. Therefore, using startswith function cannot perform the duty. But thanks for you suggestion.